# How to remove model state error for dropdown with selected option label in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC project.I have a view having a dropdownlist with an option label "Select Task".Now the integer property bound with this dropdown is not a required field.

But then too after I try to save, I get the dropdown having a red border showing that it is required. When I analysed, I found that the option label has value null.

Using firebug when I entered 0 for the value of option label, the view was saved with no model state error. Am I doing something wrong ? How to avoid it ?

```
View
```

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.projecttaskid, new       SelectList((IList<SelectListItem>)ViewData["MyTasks"], "Value", "Text"),"Select Task", new { @class = "span2" })`

`Model public int projecttaskid { get; set; }` Controller It doesn't reach the controller action.

Comment: Please post your model, view and controller code

Comment: **View**
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.projecttaskid, new SelectList((IList<SelectListItem>)ViewData["MyTasks"], "Value", "Text"),"Select Task", new { @class = "span2" })

   **Model**
public int projecttaskid { get; set; }

  **Controller**
It doesn't reach the controller action.

Comment: you should edit your question with this code instead of putting it in a comment (for readability) + show the code where your set the value of `ViewData["MyTasks"]` (probably in your controller.

Comment: Are you sure your model does not have a required decoration?

Answer (score 0):

For instant, you use an overload of `DropDownListFor` with the `optionLabel` argument (your "Select Task" argument.

If no item is selected, this will be taken as the "selected option", and return a null value for `model.projecttaskid`.

The easiest way would be to add an element with a `0` value when you create your list (`ViewData["MyTasks"]`)

With, for example :

```
Value = 0;
Text = "Select Task;
```

And use an overload of DropDownListFor without the optionLabel.

[By the way, usage of ViewModels instead of ViewData would be a good thing, but that's another problem]

****EDIT ****

We do use some extension methods to manage these cases :

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T, TValue, TText>(
            this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
            Func<T, TText> text,
            Func<T, TValue> value)
        {
            return enumerable.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = text(item).ToString(),
                Value = value(item).ToString()
            }).AsEnumerable();
        }

public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WithDefaultZeroValue(this IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems, string chooseText/* = ChooseText*/)
        {
            IList<SelectListItem> items = selectListItems.ToList();
            items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = chooseText });

            return items.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

usage

```
var myList = mySourceForDropDown.ToSelectListItem(m => m.TextField, m => m.ValueField)
                                .WithDefaultZeroValue("SelectTask")
```

Comment: I had this option for last.I thought there would be an out of box facility given in MVC, by which we can solve the issue of dropdownlist

Comment: thanx mate.You were right about the non-nullable scenario. I did the same
`items.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "Select Task",
                    Value = "0"
                });`
& finally it worked .

Answer (score 0):

`projecttaskid` is not nullable.  Unless you provide a default value for the drop down list, the model will not bind properly, which is why you are getting validation error even though the model field is not marked as `[required]`.

Edit: by default value I mean an item in the list with a value of 0, since the default value for `projecttaskid` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Enums.TenderType))), new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-val", "false" } })
```